# Install bluetooth, bluez-utils, blueman and libbluetooth-dev On CentOS +7

Tags: java, bluetooth, centos-7, bluez

I have a java project that I have to communicate with a out resource by bluetooth. So I am using BlueCove library to do that. but I know I should install bluetooth,  bluez-utils, blueman and libbluetooth-dev before using the BloueCove. My Operating System is CentOs 7+
Any one can help me to install them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found it at last...

I installed all prerequisites for blueCove by below commands in Linux CentOS 7+

$ sudo yum install *bluez *

$ sudo yum install *bluetooth *

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to install [`bluetooth_battery`](https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level%60) which depends on `libbluetooth-dev`. Installing `bluez-libs-devel` fixed my missing dependencies, therefore I presume that `bluez-libs-devel` should be used instead of `libbluetooth-dev` on RHEL-like distributions.